# Read a text file and send the content to a Azure Function in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-functions, text-files, azure-data-factory

I must have missed something big time when it comes to Azure Data Factory. This is what I want to do.
A have a textfile stored on my local network, I want to get that content (as is) and send that to a Azure function and then the azure function should work with that content to mapp it into a specific json object and send the result back to Data Factory.

But I can't find a simple way to take the content of the file and send it into the Azure Function. The closed I am getting is to use the 'lookup' activity with a dataset that have some characters as column and row delimiter that don't exist in the file. That will give me the data but wrapped in a Json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "count":1",
  "value": {
    "Prop_0":"MY_TEXT_FILES_CONTENT"
  }
}
```

But that seems a bit overkill what I want is either

```
MY_TEXT_FILES_CONTENT
```

or

```
{
 "output": "MY_TEXT_FILES_CONTENT"
}
```

I must have missed something, isn't this like one of the most common task in integration to read a simple text file to get the content of it...

Best regards
/Magnus

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, the client application can just upload the file to a BLOB in azure and have the function triggered as soon as the upload is completed. The function can start processing and internally handle the `JSON` transformation / mapping and send to the data factory.

This is suggested given the fact that you are operating on files and that they can be of a higher size also and there are API limits and streaming limitations might be there in the functions

Comment: Well not really, since the client application cant be changed. And this will only be a small part of a larger integration pipeline. I could use the blob storage as a temporary storage between the internal file storage and the azure function, but that will add more points that could failed, and it also will complicate the code in the azure function and make it more errorprone. But it might come to that I need to solve it with this "temporary" solution. Just think it's strange that there is now easy way to read a text file direct in data factory.